# Docker Volume is not mounted in Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

I have setup continues integration deployment with cloud run using a docker file, it seems when building image with cloud run the volume is not mounted in docker, with image building locally and deploying on cloud run works fine, if anyone has any idea?

[image]

Comment: 1) Cloud Run does not use Docker. Not all Dockerfile instructions are supported. 2) I have never seen the `VOLUME` command used like you are using it. Do you have a link to the docs for your example? 3) What are you trying to accomplish with the `VOLUME` instruction?

Comment: i am trying to mount the extension on directus as explained here
https://github.com/directus/directus/discussions/16989

Comment: The syntax in your post does not match your link. Double-check what you posted. Cloud Run does not support volume mounts. Creating a volume mount requires a source and target directory. Where is the source for your volume located?

Comment: here i am creating two new directories so those are the source, for one of another directory which extension, i am copying data already into that, you can see in the screenshot i shared. Above link was just example what i was trying to achieve.

Comment: Cloud Run does not support the volumes, as @John Hanley commented.  As a workaround, refer to this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/mount-a-file-as-a-volume-in-cloud-run-facc74c02cc6)