# Cloud Run v2, Volume mount causes "missing files"

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run app, deployed via Dockerfile.

The entrypoint is `/app/scripts/api.sh`.

When I mount the `.env` file onto `/app/.env` via Volume Mounts, it causes the error that:
`/app/scripts/api.sh` can't be found and hence can't run the container.

How do I mount the env file (which needs to be in the app directory) using Volume Mounts?

Answer (score 1):

The only volume mounts supported in Cloud Run V2 are **[Cloud Storage Volumes](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/cloud-storage-volume-mounts)** and **[in-memory volume](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/in-memory-volume-mounts)**. Both are still in the **[Preview](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages)** stage, which means that it is ready for testing but not yet complete.

You can [configure your environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/environment-variables#setting) using the YAML file. Alternatively, you can also look into this medium article on how to [Mount a file as a volume in Cloud Run](https://medium.com/google-cloud/mount-a-file-as-a-volume-in-cloud-run-facc74c02cc6).

Related SO posts:

- [How to Deploy a docker container with volume in Cloud Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75128715/how-to-deploy-a-docker-container-with-volume-in-cloud-run)
- [Docker Volume is not mounted in Cloud Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139914/docker-volume-is-not-mounted-in-cloud-run)